# Bonus rep for 200 rep + Meta?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, linked-accounts

I have 201 rep on Stackoverflow.com.

What exactly does this mean and how will it apply to me?

**"If you have a registered account on other sites in our network, such as Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User – with at least 200 reputation – you will receive a +100 point reputation bonus when you first log in."** - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Which part are you looking for clarification on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a "thanks for supporting our sites" bonus.

If your OpenId is associated with any account on the StackExchange network, including the original trilogy sites (StackOverflow, ServerFault, and SuperUser), and that account has accumulated at least 200 reputation points, then when you sign up on any of the other sites, you will receive a "welcome bonus" of 100 reputation for having participated in the other sites. (Holy run-on sentence, Batman!)

Is that any clearer?

Comment: this does not work when your already on? like if i ever get past 200 on stack, i will not get a 100 boost on meta?

Comment: @Andy: Honestly, I'm not sure. I know *I* got the bump even though I already had an account, but I've been here since StackOverflow was in private beta, so I and the other existing users may have just been grandfathered in.

Comment: @Andy, once you've got 200 rep on a site, you can remove your account associations and then associate the accounts again to trigger the bonus rep.

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff : Thanks so much for your comment! (I wish you had posted it as an answer)

Comment: @Linuxmint, I was more clarifying the answer AngentConundrum prodived as it wasn't really clear what you were wanting clarification on.